# Can't receive bytes over serial port but can transfer bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, uart

I have a simple application that runs on an embedded device running Linux that sends and receives bytes over UART. I have a minicom session open in my host machine to which the RS-232 USB cable is connected.

So far, I am only able to send data from the app to the serial session but not the other way around. This should indicate my UART configs including the baud rate are fine since I can send the data at least, and the serial session is also running at the same baud rate.

`select()` returns 0 which indicates the call timed out. Is it implying the socket is busy at the moment and can't be used?

Opening a socket

```
#DEVICE_PORT      "/dev/ttyHSL0"

static int buildFlowControl(Enum_FlowCtrl fc, struct termios* term)
{
    if (NO_FLOW_CTRL == fc)
    {
        term->c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;           
        term->c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);
    }
    else if (FC_RTSCTS == fc)
    {
        term->c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
        term->c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF);
    }
    else if (FC_XONXOFF == fc)
    {
        term->c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
        term->c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
int UART_Open(const char* port, unsigned int baudrate, Enum_FlowCtrl flowCtrl)
{
    int fd;
    struct termios term;
    
    fd = open(port, O_RDWR);
    
    bzero(&term, sizeof(term));
    cfmakeraw(&term);
    term.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    
    buildBaudrate(baudrate, &term);
    buildDataBit(8, &term);
    buildStopBit(1, &term);
    buildParity(PB_NONE, &term);
    buildFlowControl(flowCtrl, &term);

    term.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
    term.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
    term.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;

    term.c_oflag &= ~OCRNL;
    term.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;
    term.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    term.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    term.c_lflag &= ~IEXTEN;
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|ECHONL|ECHOCTL|ECHOPRT|ECHOKE);

    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 5;    // minimum received bytes before unblocking
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 100; // 10 SECONDS timeout

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term);
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    return fd;
}
```

Main

```
int socketFileDescriptor;

int main(void argc, char *argv[])
{
   int baudRate = atoi(argv[1]);
   socketFileDescriptor = UART_Open(DEVICE_PORT, baudRate, NO_FLOW_CTRL);   

   if (pthread_create(&threadUartRcv, NULL, UartRcv, NULL) != 0)
   { 
      // error handling
   }  ​
   while(true);  
}
```

UART receive function:

```
static void* UartRcv(void* arg)
{
    int ret;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval timeout = {5, 0};    
    char buffer[100] = {0};

    FD_ZERO(&fdset); 
    FD_SET(socketFileDescriptor, &fdset); 
    while(true)
    {
        ret = select(socketFileDescriptor + 1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout); // waits for 5 seconds for any activity on socket

        // reset the time value back to the original since it's reset by select()
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            printf("< failed to select >\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (ret == 0)
        {
            printf("< no data >\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(socketFileDescriptor, &fdset)) 
            {
                do {
                    memset(buffer, 0x0, sizeof(buffer));
                    ret = read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer, 100);
                    sleep(3);
                } while (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your real code actually exit `main` after creating the thread? If that is the case it won't work as exiting `main` will cause the thread to terminate.

Comment: `do {
                    memset(buffer, 0x0, sizeof(buffer));
                    ret = UART_Read(fd_uart, buffer, 100);
                    sleep(3);
                } while (true);` <<-- you shouldn't loop here. select guarantees **one** read to not block. Also, select() returning -1 is **not an error**. (could be EINTR/EAGAIN)

Comment: `FD_SET(fd_uart, &fdset);` What is `fd_uart`? It's definition and setting is not shown in the code. Please provide real and complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, you should re-initialise the fd_set on every iteration of the loop. (select() alters it)

Comment: BTW: how do you know that your `UartRcv(void* arg)` does not work? At the moment, it does nothing with the received data. [and it blocks after the first read]

Comment: @kaylum spot on. In the main code, I have a write() function within a loop inside main so it keeps sending data over UART. Since that part is working, I didn't include it. I just edited to have an infinite loop so it doesn't terminate

Comment: @wildplasser - in your first point, are you saying I should invoke `select()` in each iteration to ensure the socket is ready to be used prior to invoking a read call again? And about your last question: I'm trying the following behavior -- in a loop, block on the socket FD till it receives certain bytes, and then repeat. With only `O_RDWR`, it seems completely blocked...I also set VTIME and VMIN but not sure if the timeout works as expected. Possibly I'm confusing things

Comment: Why the numerous & persistent mention of *"sockets"* when there is absolutely nothing in the code posted that actually involves sockets?  Why do you think you need to use **select()** before performing a **read()**?  Your termios initialization could be broken.   The use of **bzero()** on a termios struct is just wrong (but in this case ineffective).  The other 2 statements before **tcgetattr()** are ineffective; so the state of the CREAD flag is ambiguous.

Comment: bzero() is used to zero out termios struct before using it. also as far as I've read, `CREAD` enables the receiver for receiving bytes, no?

Comment: There is no need for bogus initialization of a termios structure.  Simply call **tcgetattr()**.  Any *prior* contents will be *clobbered*, lost, *overwritten*.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)  BTW your program is not accessing a socket or UART.  It is accessing a *serial terminal*.

Comment: sure. i'm still new to socket programming the code I have is a result of me looking through different articles.

Comment: Whenever I have this problem, it's because the transmit data line is connected but the receive data line is not.  (That is, check for the possibility of a hardware problem!)

Comment: *"i'm still new to socket programming"* -- **Why the numerous & persistent mention of "socket" when there is absolutely nothing in the code posted that actually involves sockets?**  Your program is accessing a ***serial terminal***, which is not a socket.

Comment: @SteveSummit shouldn't that be taken care of by the RS-232 cable? perhaps there's some config in minicom that needs to be enabled to echo the data over to the port?

Comment: @Jazzy My point is that often the RS-232 port has been connected "by hand", and since it's a multiwire connection, it's easy to accidentally end up with one wire of the transmit/receive pair correctly connected, but the other not. (Or it's all too possible to have a defective connector or cable.) But you said you tested using minicom -- did you get both directions working that way?  If so, the cabling is fine, and my comment doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to send data from minicom by disabling the Hardware Flow Control. I'm not quite certain as to why would that solve given RTS/CTS is enabled

Comment: The simple explanation is that you have now configured the sender to ignore any flow-control, i.e. transmit unconditionally.  The real problem seems to be that you don't know what your target should use or is using. The latest source *"code"* (which has been revised numerous times since the first post) now has a **buildParity()** routine that does not configure parity, but configures flow-control in a haphazard way.  IOW if *no* flow-control is requested, then *hardware* flow-control will be enabled on the target!  And your code still has bugs as mentioned in numerous comments.

Comment: *"Do you see why would the data start flowing from terminal after disabling flow control even though it was enabled on the receiver side?"* -- I already explained that in the previous comment.  Don't assume that (all) the downvote(s) are by me.  It's not personal, but could be an indicator that the post has low value, i.e. not usable by other people because its scope is so limited or even impractical.  IOW nobody should copy your code and expect it to work  (or use this answer) because that code still has bugs.  It certainly doesn't compile cleanly.

Comment: well, I didn't include the definitions of ALL the calls particularly the ones for UART config since I thought they wouldn't be adding any value to this issue. Sure I could include them but then I may get comments saying to include minimal code. These kinds of issues aren't always reproducible since they also depend on the hardware itself. Plus copying the code without understanding isn't always suggested anyways. And I posted this as an answer because this indeed solved the issue for me though there are still some doubts...

Comment: *"...since I thought they wouldn't be adding any value to this issue."* -- You made an assumption, and it's a wrong assumption.   Your main program implies that NO_FLOW_CTRL is the termios configuration on this target.  But the (misnamed routine) code that you eventually posted indicates that  NO_FLOW_CTRL actually bizarrely configures ***hardware*** flow-control.  So by omission you mislead everyone to assume there is no flow-control in use, and of course nobody bothers to mention that you need to match flow-control settings.  It's your bad.

Comment: yes, this could've been misleading and I admit it being my mistake but what's happening in the code is hardware control flow is enabled

Comment: If you're dubious that your omission was misleading, then let me point out that you also explicitly directed focus away from serial port configuration and termios settings with the statement: *"This should indicate **my** UART configs including the baud rate are fine ..."*.  (It also reads like an assertion of competence, especially with the use of the possesive *"my"*.) That's just one more deficiency that makes this post low quality, and not likely to help future readers.